# Safari zooms automatically for portrait to landscape orientation

Tags: ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, safari

Some of the pages in my `bootstrap` site is zoomed automatically when orientation has changed from portrait to landscape.

NOTE : This seems to occur for only some of my bootstrap pages... Why?

Adding this meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

solves my problem,but it wont allow user to zoom.

Also read in many blogs that IOS has fixed this issue,but i am able to reproduce it in my `iPad` which has `iOS 7` !

Comment: Provide the Link? so i can check it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't zoomin because you've set the maximum-scale to the minimum amount (1.0) which means it won't be zoomable beyond what is rendered initially. You need to set the maximum-scale to something else between 1.0 and 10.0 in that meta tag. The default by Apple is to have the maximum-scale as 5.0 as per [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html).

[Meta viewport tag seems to be ignored completely or has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19049198/meta-viewport-tag-seems-to-be-ignored-completely-or-has-no-effect) 
Also check this too;

[Transition to iOS 7: correct viewport setting for jQuery/iPhone Webapps viewed on iPads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892491/transition-to-ios-7-correct-viewport-setting-for-jquery-iphone-webapps-viewed-o)

good luck!

Comment: Tried this one.But this dont allow user to zoom.

Comment: HI aamir, I have actually updated maximum scale to 1 because it was zooming beyond that when orientation has changed. But this is not a fix as user is not able to zoom now.

Comment: @user3240757 max scale 1.0 will not allow user to zoomin... increase the scale and check it... i also added apple documentation check that too for help...